# How to dynamically load fixtures in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hey I'm having trouble dynamically loading fixture data into my emberjs models. How should I go about doing this? The addArtist function at the bottom will add one song correctly but I'm not sure how to adapt this to loading all of the songs into the data store correctly. Is there an easier way than adding each one individually?

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 13,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    tracks: DS.hasMany('App.Tracks')
});

App.Tracks = DS.Model.extend({
    videoid: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    duration: DS.attr('number')
});

App.Artist.FIXTURES = [];
App.Tracks.FIXTURES = [];

App.loadFixtures = function(){
    $.getJSON('/artists', function(data){
        $.each(data.artists, function(i,v){
            App.Artist.createRecord(v);
        });
    });
    $.getJSON('/tracks', function(data){
        $.each(data.tracks, function(i,v){
            App.Tracks.createRecord(v);
        });
    });
};

App.addArtist = function(){
    var artist = App.Artist.createRecord({
        id: 3,
        name: 'Justin Martin'
    });
    var track = App.Tracks.createRecord({
        id: 300,
        title: 'Jungle Mix',
        duration: 200
    });
    artist.get('tracks').pushObject(track);
};
```

Sample JSON Responses:

```
{"artists":[
{"id":1,"name":"The (International) Noise Conspiracy","track_ids":[1,2,3,4]},
{"id":2,"name":"0SM","track_ids":[5]},
{"id":3,"name":"2am","track_ids":[6,7,8]}
]}

{"tracks":[
{"id":1,"videoid":"FyjmCg_VMU0","title":"Smash It Up","duration":197},
{"id":2,"videoid":"jKXWm9yi4DY","title":"Only Lovers Left Alive","duration":162},
{"id":3,"videoid":"fwbleH55CCk","title":"Up For Sale","duration":211},
{"id":4,"videoid":"50JdKhIB1EQ","title":"A New Morning, Changing Weather","duration":270},
{"id":5,"videoid":"bd6ve0ydHVo","title":"The Landing feat. Alex G - Original Mix","duration":322},
{"id":6,"videoid":"RnwVtbMW4x4","title":"Anxious","duration":238},
{"id":7,"videoid":"Yo0zsqa06ZE","title":"I Did Wrong","duration":305},
{"id":8,"videoid":"_9ydBAgg130","title":"I Love You (feat. Baekchan & Joohee)","duration":219}
]}
```

Should I include the track_ids in the Artists response or do they get added when I call this method?

```
artist.get('tracks').pushObject(track);
```

Comment: How come you're using fixtures? You should just be using the default DS.RESTAdapter if you're loading data from the server. The fixtures adapter is for use when you don't have an api to pull data from and want to define data for testing during development. See: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

Comment: Because I'm tired of trying to figure out how to use the RESTAdapter.

Comment: Ah - well, I'm afraid you probably won't have much luck with fixture adapter since it's not intended for consuming an API.

Comment: what problem do you have with the rest adapter? perhaps close this and open a question containing your issue with the rest adapter